# A computer test of a very fast primarily test

Tags: statistics, regression, pseudoprimes

Fermat's little theorem states that if $p$ is a prime and $a$ is any integer not divisible by $p$, then $a^{p-1} - 1$ is divisible by $p$.
$$a^{p-1}\equiv 1\pmod p$$

This can be used to test if a number $n$ is a composite, which is implied of 
$a^{n-1}\not\equiv 1\pmod n$ for any $a$ not divisible by $n$. I have ran a test for pseudo random generated single cell numbers with the number $x$ of binary digits, to get the number of tests before a composite number $n$ gives 
$(n-2)^{n-1}\equiv 1\pmod n$ and got the following diagram:

[image]
Assuming that my computer test is accurate, how to estemate the probability of an error using Fermat as an primality test for big numbers?

The test takes about 0.02 seconds on my computer for a number with $100$ binary digits. How to estimate the probability of getting a "false prime" by testing $100,000,000,000$ times ($100$-digit) pseudo random numbers, which would take about 80 years? Is it possible to say something about the accuracy of the estimation?

Comment: Since for odd $n$ we have $(n-2)^{n-1}\equiv 2^{n-1}\pmod{n}$, you seem to be looking for Fermat pseudoprimes to the base $2$. The standard upper bound for the number of these $\le x$ is I think due to Pomerance.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: Okay thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. I am not sure whether you are confining attention to $(n-2)^{n-1}$ or whether you are possibly considering other bases.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, I just picked n-2 to investigate the statistics. I guess the chance of finding a random lier with the same number of bits as Arnault's number is practically zero. I sometimes want very fast primarily tests, rather than much slower but safer tests.

Comment: You may want to look at Rabin's probabilistic  test, which uses similar ideas.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, I use RM for exact primarily tests up to 64 bit, http://forthmath.blogspot.se/2015/10/pseudo-prime-number-tests.html but want something faster for very big numbers.